# Curious error on Chrome and Android but page works fine on Internet Explorer

Tags: php, forms, google-chrome, internet-explorer, browser

A curious error has appeared out of nowhere on one of the (php based) pages on my website. The page in question has mostly php code but also some javascript. It works perfectly fine on Internet Explorer and Firefox - a user can select the BEGINNER level and FIRST QUIZ, a user name (repeated) and then take a quiz with no problem at all!

On Chrome and Android however, it keeps resorting to asking the user to "please enter quiz password" - even though there is no password for this quiz (and as mentioned, it works fine and goes straight to the quiz in IE). Furthermore it works fine on Safari (IPHONE) as well!

The website URL is here:

http://www.teachyourselfpython.com/testandtrack_v5/index.php

(to test it, simply select BEGINNER and INTRO to PROGRAMMING quiz - then enter your username twice, consent (tick box) and then the quiz should appear when you click the submit button. (note that it will work fine in IE and Safari). It may be that it will work for you taking it, in which case, what is wrong with the display and form input on my end?

Can anyone explain why this is happening?
One suggestion is that it may have something to do with the javascript?(but why is it only happening in Chrome - and note that just yesterday it worked perfectly fine in Chrome too!) Nothing was changed so why this sudden error?

The html part of the page that generates the section that relates to the quiz password being generated (note that the first quiz HAS NO password associated with it) is below:

```
        <div id="head" align="center">
            <img src="img/typbanner.png" alt="www.teachyourselfpython.com" width=600 height=180 />
        </div>
     <br>
      <p>Please note: Best viewed in <a href="https://www.google.co.uk/chrome/browser/features.html?brand=CHBD&ds_kid=43700010857960474&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIr-OM29D32AIVzLDtCh0mHQS1EAAYASABEgKoUfD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds&dclid=CNua29zQ99gCFbEi0wod7UUM2g" target="_blank">Chrome</a> or <a href="https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/new/?scene=2" target=" _blank"> Firefox</a>. <i>Note : Beta Testing</i></p>
        <div id="main_body" align="center">
            <h2>Time to try a <big><b>TEST!</b></big></h2>

            <form id="myForm" name="onlyForm" action="quiz.php" class="home"  method="POST">
                <select name="quiz_level" id="quiz_form" class="form-control">
                    <option disabled selected="true">-- Select The level of your Test --</option>
                    <option value="Beginner">Beginner</option>
                    <option value="Intermediate">Intermediate</option>
                    <option value="Advanced">Advanced</option>
                </select>
<select  class="form-control" name="quiz" id="got_quiz" style="display:none;"> <!--onchange="showUser(this.value)"-->


  </select>
  <input type="password" name="quiz_password" placeholder="Enter Quiz Password" required id="password" style="display:none;" />

            <h3>Rules</h3>
```

The bit of the php code referring to the generation of the error "Hey, please enter the password", is pasted below: Please note however, that there is nothing wrong with the code as it works PERFECTLY in Internet Explorer. Safari. and Firefox!!!!!

```
while (mysqli_num_rows($m_questions_from_DB)<1) {
            $user_msg = 'Hey, weird, but it seems there are no questions in this quiz!';
            header('location: index.php?user_msg='.$user_msg.'');
            exit();
        }
        if($_POST['consent'] != 1){
            $user_msg = 'Hey, You have to consent first to begin the quiz!';
            header('location: index.php?user_msg='.$user_msg.'');
            exit();
        }else if(($_POST['class_name'] == "non" && !empty($_POST['school_pin'])) || ($_POST['class_name'] != "non" && empty($_POST['school_pin']))){
            if($_POST['class_name'] == "non"){ echo "aakakakak"; }
            $user_msg = 'Hey, You have to insert correct school pin and choose your class'.$_POST['school_pin'].$_POST['class_name'];
            header('location: index.php?user_msg='.$user_msg.'');
            exit();
        }elseif($quiz_pass != '0' && empty($_POST['quiz_password'])){
            $user_msg = 'Hey, Enter a correct Quiz password';
            header('location: index.php?user_msg='.$user_msg.'');
            exit();
        }elseif(!empty($_POST['quiz_password']) && $_POST['quiz_password'] != $quiz_pass){
            $user_msg = 'Hey, Enter a correct Quiz password';
            header('location: index.php?user_msg='.$user_msg.'');
            exit();
        }
     //setting Question No. to 1 on quiz page(necessary due to rand() above)
        $m_display_ID = 1;
```

Comment: You are mixing `else if` and `elseif`.

Comment: roll - please note that there is nothing wrong with the code as such, because it works FINE in IE and Firefox and SAFARI

Comment: It is clearly some strange error to do with Chrome ....there are two developers looking into it and they don't have an answer yet. It's not the code, I re-iterate, as the code works fine in IE and Firefox

Comment: one developer thinks it may be a javascript issue.

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer looking more closely.... is it possible chrome has suddenly stopped "reading" the elseif   ....can you specifically point out what it should be and the error ..and also perhaps suggest why it is still working in Firefox and internet explorer? Hugely appreciated Thanks!